# A guy looked at me in the bathroom, what should I have said

Tags: phrase-request

You know those situations where you think back on the situation and wish you would have said something different? Here is one of those.

**Situation**

I am a male in my lower 20's and I was using the urinal at an airport in China. It was an odd hour of the day and the bathroom was empty. A minute later a Chinese man, 40'ish years old, comes in and chooses the urinal beside me. If you are a male you know this is against the bro code...

While doing our thing the other guy peers over the divider at my 下面的 (private parts) and looks at me and smiles.

I was so taken aback that I froze and couldn't say anything, not to mention my Chinese was not that good at the time. I was also shocked and a little angry.

**Question**

What would be appropriate to say in this situation? I was pretty angry at the time.

**Thoughts**

I feel like I would have said something like:

你干看着什么啦？！
你是农村人吗？
天啊。

Does those sentences make sense in that situation? What is an appropriate response in Chinese?

Comment: it's fine, but why would you think this have any thing to do with '农村人'

Comment: How about 你没有自己的吗？Also be sure you have some MMA training :)

Comment: @Manx I heard it was an insult, but wasn't sure how it is used.

Comment: @Manx "I heard it was an insult, but wasn't sure how it is used" 农村人 is equivalent to calling an Englishman a "peasant" However, in China, during certain times in its history, peasants were heroes. Now, perhaps perceptions might have changed when "peasants / heroes" have taken on new definitions.

Comment: okay ... I see why you think this is an insult.

Comment: I suggest 看什么看？ or if you're in Beijing 瞧什么瞧？  Or maybe 你干嘛呀？ But Chinese people break these ”codes“ all the time.  (Currently we're required to maintain 1m separation in queues, but if you do so, Chinese people will push in front of you.)

Comment: "你干看着什么啦？！" doesn't sound correct.  The use of 干 may be dialectal.  It's not a standard mandarin.

Comment: Just so everyone knows. I am not a confrontational person and, had I known how, I would have said something gentle.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any "appropriate" response for the old guy since his behavior is abnormal. But you can think about it if it happens in your hometown and how would you react or say in English? Maybe some curse words or yelling.

Answer (score 1):

There are thousand of things you can say. Since you already have something in mind, let's explore it

> 你干看着什么啦？！ (What are you fXXking looking at) is not what we commonly use the 'F' word.  You could say "你他媽的看什麼? (what are you Fxxking looking at)
>
> 你是农村人吗？ 天啊。(are you a country boy? My God) being from the countryside is not an insult in China. And Chinese rarely use 天啊(My God) As an angry exclamation, you  could say. "你是變態的嗎? 真是的!" (are you perverted? Really!)

But saying so would escalate  the situation, I do not recommend That

My suggestion is : "這位先生，你這樣很沒禮貌呢!" (Sir, you are being rude here!) or  "這位先生，你這樣很不文明呢!" (Sir, you are being uncivilized here!)

And you should just walk away after showing your superior civicness

(The Chinese government is very keen on educating its citizens to be more civil, so that they wouldn't lose face internationally. Most Chinese would agree with you if you just point out the true. But if you insult that man, people might think you are equally  uncivilized)

**Edition:**

I found this funny

"你看个鸟啊？" literally mean "Are you looking at a bird?" , But the phrase actually mean "What the (dick = F word) are you looking at?

Comment: I suppose in this, (some might say comic), situation, much depends on the socio-cultural attitudes of the nationalities involved. If this happens in an English-European context, the advice given on what to say might well be, "Makes your day, doesn't it"? or "I've never used an enlarger, in case you are wondering"

Comment: Uh, "being from the countryside is not an insult in China," really?

Answer (score 1):

In situation like this, I think you can just say go away or back off or something else in English if you are not comfortable.

I don't recommend saying something like
"這位先生，你這樣很沒禮貌/不文明呢"
because it may be too soft
這位先生 and 呢 should be dropped

Using 你是农村人吗？天啊。
is odd because 农村人 has nothing to do with being gay or not
天啊 is more like the response to something like natural disaster or if he said something ridiculous.

I think you can say something like
滚开 or 我要報警
to stop his behavior

If you want to say something gentle,
No, 去 or 滚
can be used but I doubt if gentle words like these would be helpful in that situation.

Comment: wait, 滚 is a gentle word ?

Comment: Just one word 滚 can be gentle, compared to 滚开, in this situation. It depends on how you say it. I don't want to suggest something like 不要 because it will probably make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

What the heck are you looking at ?

看什么你啊 ？

看什么看 ？

看什么呀 ？

What the heck are you doing ?

干吗 ？

干吗你 ？

Sarcastic. Did you have a good look ? Like what you saw ?

好看吗 ？

大不大 ？

For fucks sake !

我靠 ！

Instead of the ''country person'' remark it is common to use 素质 ''quality of person''.

没素质 ！ Spoken to yourself out loud for him to hear.

Keep it simple. I'd just go with 干吗 ？